VS Code, inserts "Resolving Dependencies..." whenever I save
I'm using VSCode and today, whenever I save a file, something is literally inserting "Resolving Dependencies..." wherever my cursor is when I save. I cannot, for the life of me, figure out where this is coming from and need some guidance. This is a real line being inserted, so it breaks the code. It is happening on every save.
I have 58 extensions installed, and have gone through I think all of them disabling and re-enabling them. I use Vim, but I have disabled and removed that, and re-enabled.
How do I better track this down?
Is there any way to start with a clean version of VSCode and build up? or would a fresh application share global settings?
I'm on OSX


Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled command in the command palette)? If not, then do an extension bisect to figure out what extension is causing it.
